# How to reverse video in different software packages

Tags: editing

One of the basic edits one can make to a video is reversing it such that it plays backwards.
The goal of this community wiki is to show beginning users how to reverse footage with different video editors.

When adding answers, please try to make the guide as easy as possible as this is aimed towards beginning users.

---

### List of software in alphabetical order

- [After Effects](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/5637/2178)
- [Premiere Pro](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/5638/2178)
- [Vegas Movie Studio & Vegas Pro](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/5646/1760)

Comment: Are you interested in Vegas Movie Studio and Vegas Pro?

Comment: Just put any video software package that you have access to in this wiki. I'm thinking of making a similar wiki for audio editors.

Answer (score 2):

### After Effects

There are three steps involved when you want to reverse footage in After Effects.

1. Import the footage
   Go to `File -> Import -> File...` select your footage and click `Open`
2. Create new composition
   In the `Project Panel` drag your footage to the new composition button as shown in the image below:

[image: Drag footage to new composition button]

3. Reverse the footage
   Now in the `Composition Panel` right click on your footage and go to `Time -> Time-Reverse Layer` as shown in the image below:

[image: Time-Reverse Layer]

Now your footage is reversed and you only need to export it with the settings you desire by clicking `Composition -> Make Movie...`

Answer (score 2):

### Premiere Pro

1. Make a new project
   Go to `File -> New -> Project`. Set the folder and project name and choose the sequence preset that fits your footage with regards to the dimensions, frame rate, frame aspect ratio, etc...
2. Import your footage
   Go to `File -> Import`, choose your footage and click `Open`.
3. Put the footage in the sequence
   Drag and drop the footage from the `Project Panel` to the timeline in the `Sequence Panel` as shown in the image below:

[image: Drag drop from project to sequence]

4. Reverse the clip
   Right click on the footage in the timeline and go to `Speed/Duration...`. In the window that shows up check the `Reverse Speed` checkbox and click OK.

[image: Right click on footage]

[image: Reverse speed checkbox]

Now your footage is reversed and you can export it by going to `File -> Export -> Media`.

Answer (score 1):

### Vegas Movie Studio & Vegas Pro

Assuming you have put the desired clip(s) in the timeline.

Right click on the clip and a menu will appear, check 'reverse' and this will reverse the clip. You will get confirmation by a reverse arrow appearing at the leading edge of the clip in the timeline. Note, you will need to do this for both video and audio tracks separately. To undo go back and uncheck it.